# My CSS is not working with boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting to build a webpage using **Bootstrap 3** (latest version) and for some reason I can't seem to add a background image.

The coding is correct, all files are in their proper folders, etc.

Finally I decided to create another webpage with the exact coding the only difference is that my css stylesheet is not in the css folder.  I refresh and the background image appears.  When i move the css file back into the css folder, the image is gone.

What is happening?  the name of the file is correct, I have added the correct path and I added some other styling besides the background image and they seem to be working perfectly whether or not the css file is in or out of the folder.

HTML WHERE CSS FILE IS IN THE CSS FOLDER

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
</html>
```

HTML WHERE CSS FILE IS NOT IN THE CSS FOLDER

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.container {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

[Root FOlder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Xo8.png)

Comment: try changing background url relative to the css folder

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide relevant codes along with your question. Also, do check out this link [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask questions here.

Comment: Hi ! could you please add both the html and css files to your question ? so we can see what's going on  ?

Comment: Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I'm trying to add the coding but getting an error

Comment: make sure that the image is in the same place as the CSS file is - can you confirm that?

Comment: the image is in the root folder.  Shouldn't the image be in the root folder or img folder?  I have been told that all css should be in one folder and all img should in their own folder to keep the root folder tidy and organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the css file to the css folder the image url in the css file should be changed too. If your css file is in the css folder and image is in the root directory then the image url should be
 background: url(../background.jpg)
Means go up one folder and search for image.

Comment: so how the img url should be?  The image i'm using is not in any folder as yet.

Comment: Where is the image then?

Comment: it's in the root folder, that's why the link is just " background: url(background.jpg)"

Comment: If you want to place the css file in the css folder and image in root, use  "background: url(../background.jpg)". The two dots makes it go from the css folder to root to search for the image.

Comment: it works!! I feel kinda dumb ,_,     the image didn't show because of dots.  Thanks!!!

Comment: We have all been there at some point. Cheers